# PHP process IMG with specific width & order…

Tags: php, image, width

I want the IMG tags inside `$_POST['textarea']`, to change from this:

Example:

```
$_POST['textarea'] = <b>Some example Text</b><br> <img src="image_1.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="250" height="100" /> <u>some more text</u><br> <img src="image_2.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="50" height="20" />
```

to a format like this:

```
$final = <b>Some example Text</b> <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image_1.jpg" title="bla bla"><img src="image_1.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="250" height="100" /></a> </u>some more text</u> <img src="image_2.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="50" height="20" />
```

1. How can I add class="fancybox" only to IMG tags with a width greater than 50px ?
2. How can I process all IMG tags in order with their according values?
3. How can I print the whole content of Var $_POST['textarea'] with all Tags and Text & the updated IMG tags, in the Var $final?

Comment: You probably would want to use a DOM parser like [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: There is a missing `<a>`, just saying ...

Comment: Do you want <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="image_1.jpg" title="bla bla">  fixed??

Answer (score 0):

Include simple_html_dom.php in your page. download it from http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_simplehtmldom/downloads/simplehtmldom/1.10/simplehtmldom_1_10.zip/

```
 <?php
require_once('controller/simple_html_dom.php');
$str = 'Some example Text <img src="image_1.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="250" height="100" /> 
        some more text <img src="image_2.jpg" alt="bla bla" width="50" height="20" />';

$html = str_get_html($str);
$img = array();
foreach ($html->find('img') as $images) {
    if($images->getAttribute('width') > 50) {
        $img[] = '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="'.$images->getAttribute('src').'" title="bla bla">'.$images.'</a>';
    } else {
        $img[] = $images;
    }
}

$full = '';

$i = 0;
foreach ($html->find('text') as $text) {
    $full .= $text.$img[$i];
    $i++;
}
echo $full;
?>
```

Comment: Then remove the condition > 50

Comment: please paste both html content. one that you are getting from textarea and another that you want exactly. that's all.

Comment: $_POST['textarea'] = <b>some text</b>
$final = some text --> tags are missing